# : (colons in parameter names going through zuul. Maybe spring related

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

When passing in a url with a parameter called `?name:content=john` I get the following error (see stacktrace below).

So narrowed it down to `org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents` when it calls `expandQueryParams` method.

It then calls `getVariableName` and returns in this case name because it has stripped the trailing `:content` off.

I am sure there is a reason for this, but is there anyway I can stop it happening as it is failing to find the name param later on as seen in the stacktrace below.

Any help with this would be MASSIVELY appreciated.  It is the last obstacle to putting Zuul live for us.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Map has no value for 'name'
at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents$MapTemplateVariables.getValue(UriComponents.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expandUriComponent(UriComponents.java:230) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.expandQueryParams(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:343) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.expandInternal(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:329) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.expandInternal(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:47) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expand(UriComponents.java:152) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriTemplate.expand(UriTemplate.java:97) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.ProxyRequestHelper.getQueryString(ProxyRequestHelper.java:274)
```

Comment: Just as an aside, the other option appears to be overriding the SimpleHostRoutingFilter as the method call :  'Map<String, Object> info = this.helper.debug(verb, uri, headers, params, requestEntity);' seems to be the one causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

The bug here is in lines 264 and 266 of `ProxyRequestHelper`:

```
  singles.put(param + i, value);
  query.append("={");
  query.append(param + i);
```

Since param contains a colon, this is interpreted `UriTemplate` in the subsequent expansion.

One solution is to replace the colon with a character that won't be interpreted when parsing an processing the `UriTemplate`, and that won't cause a clash with another query parameter. For example, if we replaced `:` with `!` then there would be the chance that both `name:content=john` and `name!content=jane` appeared in the original query string. To avoid this problem we can first replace all instances of `!` in param with `!!`, and then all instances of `:` with `!`.

Bug raised here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1193